# Export mysql data to JSON in a nested and recursivelty way starting from a table?

Tags: mysql, json, export

I have seen several examples to export MySQL tables to JSON, however such examples export data in an aggregated way. For example, take a database where you have two tables "Invoice head" and "Invoice details". "Invoice details" is a child of "Invoice head".The data in JSON is usually represented like:

```
    {
    "invoice_head": [
        {
            "number": 1, 
            "cliente": "Carlos", 
            "date": "2016-12-12"
        }, 
        {
            "number": 2, 
            "cliente": "Fernando", 
            "date": "2017-01-01"
        }
    ],
    "invoice_details": [
        {
            "headnumber": 1,
        "lineno": 1,
            "product": "Shoes", 
            "quantity": 2
        }, 
        {
            "headnumber": 1,
        "lineno": 2,
            "product": "Socks", 
            "quantity": 1
        },
    {
            "headnumber": 2,
        "lineno": 1,
            "product": "Laptop", 
            "quantity": 1
        }
    ],
}
```

I need to export data in a nested way:

```
{
    "invice_head": [
        {
            "number": 1, 
            "cliente": "Carlos", 
            "date": "2016-12-12",
        "invice_details": [
          {
              "headnumber": 1,
              "lineno": 1,
              "product": "Shoes", 
              "quantity": 2
          }, 
          {
              "headnumber": 1,
              "lineno": 2,
              "product": "Socks", 
              "quantity": 1
          }
        ]
        }, 
        {
            "number": 2, 
            "cliente": "Fernando", 
            "date": "2017-01-01"
        "invice_details": [
          {
              "headnumber": 2,
              "lineno": 1,
              "product": "Laptop", 
              "quantity": 1
          }
        ]
        }
    ]
}
```

For this I guess one needs to start in a table and recursively go through its childs for each record.

Does anybody knows if there is anything that does it? I don't want to reinvent the wheel.